# iOS map app that can load MBTiles tileset

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, maps, mapping

Are there any good map apps that will allow me to load the map from an MBTiles tileset file?

I'm looking for something that will allow me to use the map offline while hiking.

Comment: See [this Meta answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a hardware/software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you one of these :

- [Guru Maps](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/guru-maps/id321745474), its free version allow you to load 3 offline MBTiles. Their paid version is quite expensive - 50$ but the app is well-made.
- [OpenMapTiles](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/osm2vectortiles/id1089255502), if you want to use OpenStreetMap vectors only.
- [MBTiles GPS](https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/mbtiles-gps/id592703465), the app interface is basic but it's free.
- [MapTiler Mobil‪e‬](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/geoeditor-for-maptiler/id1168561747), I've never tried it but I heard great feedback about it.

Comment: Also Map Plus
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/map-plus/id438868200